# Probability that two random points on a random triangle come from the same edge?

Tags: probability

I am writing a program that picks two random points from a triangle from different edges. I am using rejection sampling so I am curious about what the probability that these two points fall on the side is.

Update: A simulation was done by randomly picking three points uniformly on a unit circle (by angle).

To select the two points on the side of the triangle, the perimeter p of the triangle is computed and two random numbers are picked from the interval [0, p]. These two numbers representing the locations of the two points on the side of the triangle, as if you travel along the side of the triangle in the same order that the three points were selected.

The probability after 10 million simulations turns out to be somewhere around 39.2%..

Comment: The randomness of the triangle make this pretty impossible to calculate by hand.

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: About this random triangle ... I interpret that it means that the side lengths of the triangle are random variables, right? Do you know about the distribution of those?

Comment: It's just three random points on an unit circle,

Comment: And how are you picking the points from the edges? Are you picking uniformly along the perimeter? Or something else? To be honest, the easiest way to know the rejection rate is just to measure it by running it a million times and counting it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Nice question.  Personally, I would simply assume that three random numbers are chosen from $[0, 2\pi)$ {AKA $[0^\circ, 360^\circ)$}, and that the points are determined by the angles that each corresponding radius makes with the horizontal.  While this seems unambiguous and natural, I am curious whether the original poster concurs.

Comment: Similar to [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) it is impossible to calculate this without knowing what precisely you mean by "random points on a random triangle"

Comment: @user2661923 I don't follow. Liu already stated that  the three vertices are chosen from a unit circle (presumably three angles chosen uniformly from $[0,2\pi)$ ), but I was asking about the two points that are then chosen on the perimeter of that triangle. It makes no sense to choose those via angles, as the triangle might not encompass the centre of that unit circle.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I guess my previous comment was poorly worded.  I was referring to only how the $3$ vertices are selected.  For each such selection, the lengths of each of the $3$ sides of the triangle are determined, which determines the desired probability, *for* *that* *group* *of* *3* *vertices*.  So, for you have a function $p(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ which determines the probability as a function of the angles, re the angles determine the side lengths.  Then you use Calculus.  There is the shortcut of assuming, without loss of generality that $\alpha < 0 = \beta < \gamma.$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis re previous comment, if you have an equilateral triangle, then $p = (1/3)$, while if you have a 45-45-90 triangle, then $p = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2 + \sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{1}{2 + \sqrt{2}}\right)^2.$

Comment: @user10354138 Tricky point.  If you accept my algorithm for selecting the angles, which determines the lengths of each side of the triangle, and you presume that the side lengths are $a,b,c ~: ~(a + b + c) = P$, then it seems to me that the desired probability (in terms of $a,b,c$) is $\frac{a^2}{P^2} + \frac{b^2}{P^2} + \frac{c^2}{P^2}.$

Comment: To the OP: you will notice that no one has stepped up with anything more than questions or moderate hints.  mathSE protocol, as represented by [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) indicates that you should edit your question to provide a brief description of the source of the problem, your math background, and a reasonable attempt to solve the problem on your own.  The attempt does not have to even approach success, but must simply represent a good faith effort.  ...see next comment.

Comment: Clarifications also belong in the question, rather than in comments.  Two issues that come to mind are how are the vertices selected (i.e. as I suggested, or some other way) and once the vertices are selected, how are the points selected (i.e. randomly along the perimeter, or some other way)?  Also, if you need to express math, please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: My bad for the ambiguity, I did Monte Carlo ten million times since I'm just a software guy who never use calculus and it seems that the probably is somewhere around 39%. I thought this might have some "clever" solution so I posted here. Apologize if it is ill formed, will update with details.